# Cache Policy - caching only if request succeeded

Tags: caching, apigee

I have enabled some cache policies on a few resources end points. System works quite well, response is cached, the following requests hit the cache, cache is correctly refreshed when I set it to be refreshed.

My only concern is that sometimes a client makes a request that does not hit the cache (for example, because the cache must be refreshed), the server in that moment returns an error (it can happen, it's statistic...) and so the cached response is not a "normal" response (e.g. 2xx) but a 4xx, or a 5xx response.

I would like to know if it is possible to cache the response only if, for example, the server response code is 2xx.

I didn't find any example on Apigee docs for doing this, also if there are some parameters for the cache policy called "SkipCachePopulation" that I think I can use for this purpose.

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you are using response-cache which is a out of the box policy by Apigee the defaut behaviour is to cache 200 responses. Here is the link http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/reduce-latency-using-responsecache

Comment: Uhm.. In this moment the page is not reachable, but I don't remember seeing clearly this in the docs. In addition to this, we are already having some problems in caching with response code different than 200.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the SkipCachePopulation field of ResponseCache. It uses a condition to determine when the cache population will not occur. Here is an example:

```
<SkipCachePopulation>response.status.code >= 400</SkipCachePopulation>
```